# Check if File Exists and then append Number to Name

Tags: batch-file

As seen in the title, I am wondering if I can name a .txt file in consequence of a verification of other files that are located in the same folder...

Before even creating my new file, I tried this but it doesn't work since I get an error `The system cannot find the file specified.` and I can't use `Traces!i!.txt` as a variable even if I define it later:

```
@Echo Off 
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
Set dir=C:\...\myFolder\
Set /A i=1 
for /f %%a in ('dir %dir%Traces*.txt /b') do ( 
   Set file=%%a 
   Set /A result=!i! - !file:~6,-4! 
   If "!result:~0,1!"=="-" ( Set /A i=!file:~6,-4! + 1 ) 
   If "!result:~0,1!"=="0" ( Set /A i=!i! + 1 ) 
) 
Echo Traces!i!.txt 
ENDLOCAL 
pause
```

Also, is there a way that I get the final chosen name as a variable ?

I want the files in my folder to look like:

> ```
> list1.txt
> list2.txt
> list3.txt
> ```

The next time when I create a new file, its name is supposed to be `list4.txt`, so I need a program that actually check for other files like I said before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "dir=C:\...\myFolder\"
set "i=0"

:get_filename
Set /a "i+=1"
if exist "%dir%Traces%i%.txt" goto :get_filename
set "filename=Traces%i%.txt"

echo "%dir%%filename%"
endlocal
pause
```

Can just use `goto` a label to loop to get an indexed filename. Once the 1st indexed filename is not found, `filename` is set with the value of the indexed filename available for creation.

Answer (score 1):

If the number suffixes are always consecutive, you could sort the file names so that the highest number can be retrieved. Since batch scripting is only capable of pure alphabetic sorting, you need to pad the number suffixes with zeros to the left to get a fixed width, then alphabetic sorting results in the same order as alpha-numeric one.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_TARGET=D:\path\to\target\dir"   & rem // (path to the target directory)
set "_PREFIX=Traces"                  & rem // (constant file name prefix)
set "_EXT=.txt"                       & rem // (file name extension with `.`)
set "_TEMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path to a temporary file)

rem // Change into target directory:
pushd "%_TARGET%" && (
    rem // Write to temporary file:
    > "%_TEMPF%" (
        rem // Loop through all matching file names:
        for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "%_PREFIX%*%EXT%"') do (
            rem // Store current base file name:
            set "NAME=%%~nF"
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of `!`:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Remove prefix from base file name, pad number with 10 zeros:
            set "NUM=!NAME:*%_PREFIX%=!" & set "PAD=0000000000!NUM!"
            rem // Return 10-digit number plus `|` plus original number (suffix):
            echo(!PAD:~-10!^|!NUM!
            endlocal
        )
    )
    rem // Restore previous working directory:
    popd
)

rem // Reset variable that will receive the resulting highest number (suffix):
set "ITEM="
for /F "tokens=2 delims=| eol=|" %%E in ('sort "%_TEMPF%"') do (
    set "ITEM=%%E"
)
rem // Clean up temporary file:
del "%_TEMPF%"

rem // Check whether there were matching files:
if defined ITEM (
    rem // Increment found highest number:
    set /A "ITEM+=1"
    rem // Return next free file path and name:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!_TARGET!\%_PREFIX%!ITEM!%_EXT%
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```